# When I click on the RecyclerView Item in MainActivity I want the TextView in MainActivity to display Item's title

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, recyclerlistview

[>>>>>>>MAIN ACTIVITY XML<<<<<<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQkoK.png)

As you can see the TextView is on the top, that's where I want to display the title of selected RecyclerView item. Most of the tutorials and blog teach to navigate to next activity when an item is clicked, but that isn't something I am looking for.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemAdapterCallback {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Item> itemList;
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    private SearchView searchView;
    TextView itemname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize(savedInstanceState);
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void initialize(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.clearFocus();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filterList(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void filterList(String newText) {
        List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : itemList) {
            if (item.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        if (filteredList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            itemAdapter.setFilteredList(filteredList);
        }
    }

    private void initializeLogic() {
        RecyclerView();
    }

    private void RecyclerView () {
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        //  Adding Data to Item List
        itemList.add(new Item("Black", R.drawable.android_black));
        itemList.add(new Item("Blue", R.drawable.android_blue));
        itemList.add(new Item("Green", R.drawable.android_green));
        itemList.add(new Item("Pink", R.drawable.android_pink));
        itemList.add(new Item("Red", R.drawable.android_red));
        itemList.add(new Item("Yellow", R.drawable.android_yellow));
        itemList.add(new Item("Black", R.drawable.android_black));
        itemList.add(new Item("Blue", R.drawable.android_blue));
        itemList.add(new Item("Green", R.drawable.android_green));
        itemList.add(new Item("Pink", R.drawable.android_pink));
        itemList.add(new Item("Red", R.drawable.android_red));
        itemList.add(new Item("Yellow", R.drawable.android_yellow));

        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicker() {
        //????????????????        
    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private String itemName;
    private int itemImage;

    public Item(String itemName, int itemImage) {
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getItemImage() {
        return itemImage;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> itemList;
    int row_index = -1;
    private ItemAdapterCallback callback;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> itemList, ItemAdapterCallback callback) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void setFilteredList(List<Item> filteredList) {
        this.itemList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_item, parent, false );
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Item item = itemList.get(position);
        holder.itemNameTv.setText(item.getItemName());
        holder.itemImageView.setImageResource(item.getItemImage());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ////////////////////////////
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item is clicked" + item.getItemName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked " + position + " " + item.getItemName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                callback.onItemClicker();
            }
        });

        if (row_index == position) {
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        } else {
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (itemList == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return itemList.size();
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView itemNameTv;
        public ImageView itemImageView;
        public CardView cardView;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eachCardView);
            itemNameTv =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.eachItemTextView);
            itemImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eachItemImageView);
        }
    }

}
```

**ItemAdapterCallback** (Interface)

```
public interface ItemAdapterCallback {
    void onItemClicker();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing few things here.

1- if you want to get the title from the adapter you will need to pass the title in your Callback Interface

```
public interface ItemAdapterCallback {
void onItemClicker(String title);}
```

2- after this change you will override the onItemClickerCallback in your mainActivity
it will look like this

```
 @Override
public void onItemClicker(String title) {
      // your title , 
      itemname.setText(title);
}
```

3- in onClick function of the adapter add this line

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if(callback!=null){
              callback.onItemClicker( item.getItemName());
           }
        }
    });
```

that's all you need to do to show the title in your mainActivity from adapter.

Comment: Thanks for offering the correct solution

Comment: if it helps you please mark this as correct answer. so that it can help others